# Writing MS Word 2007 XML

Tags: ms-word, openxml, wordprocessingml

How would I write Word 2007 XML (WordProcessingML) on my own? I have a requirement to do so, where I need to write a Word 2007 XML format for a Word template. The important thing is I should convert a Word template doc to XML (by zipping it, etc), where I need to write Word 2007 XML with those respective tags. How can I do this?

Comment: @user270066: just wanted to follow up to see if the below answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

[docx4j](http://dev.plutext.org/trac/docx4j)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "on your own," but there is an existing API for this:

[Apache POI - the Java API for Microsoft Documents](http://poi.apache.org/)

If it doesn't do what you need it to, just extend it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [OpenXMLDeveloper](http://www.openxmldeveloper.org) - you can get most of the information there on WordprocessingML and links out to other places.